# How is the formula for calculating probability derived?

Tags: probability

Why does the probability  = the number of favorable outcomes divided by the total number of outcomes? It is a really dumb question but it has been stuck in my head for days now.

Comment: Are you asking why this is the definition and not something else?

Comment: @SeanRoberson yes I am confused on why it is defined this way

Comment: What you have written is an estimate of the underlying probability.  A "frequentist" sees this as the intrinsic meaning of probability.  Another school-of-thought is the "subjectivist" that assigns probabilities according to belief.  As long as probabilities are consistent (non-negative, universe of non-overlapping events sum to one), one can assign probabilities differently than somebody else, and both are "valid" descriptions.

Comment: perhaps this is the "classicalist" definition. there are three main branches according to my textbook. as for why, you made the assumption that the outcomes are equally likely to occur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula is incorrect.

The probability of an event is able to be said to be equal to the total number of favorable outcomes divided by the total number of outcomes **only** in the case that *it is known that the outcomes are equally likely to occur*.  If it is unknown that the outcomes are equally likely to occur, then we may *not* use this as a method of calculation.

Why does it work in such a case?  *Because the outcomes are equally likely to occur!*

If our sample space is $\Omega = \{\omega_1,\omega_2,\omega_3,\dots,\omega_n\}$ then we have $\Pr(\{\omega_i\})=\Pr(\{\omega_j\})$ for each $i,j$ *by our hypothesis that each outcome is equally likely to occur*.

We see then that since $\Pr(\Omega)=1$ by definition and that $\Pr(\Omega)=\Pr(\{\omega_1,\omega_2,\dots,\omega_n\})=\Pr(\{\omega_1\})+\Pr(\{\omega_2\})+\dots+\Pr(\{\omega_n\})=n\cdot \Pr(\{\omega_1\})$ that we have as a result $\Pr(\{\omega_i\})=\frac{1}{n}$ for each $i$.

Finally, given that an event $A = \{\omega_1,\omega_2,\dots,\omega_k\}$ we have $\Pr(A)=\Pr(\{\omega_1\})+\dots+\Pr(\{\omega_k\})=k\cdot\frac{1}{n} = \frac{k}{n}$, the aforementioned formula.  This all, of course, still being predicated on the hypothesis that the outcomes were equally likely to occur.  Without that, we could not have come to this conclusion.

---

As an example of a case where the formula does not work... there are only two outcomes when playing the lottery.  You either win or you lose.  However, you don't win the lottery with probability $\frac{1}{2}$ despite winning the lottery being one of the two possible outcomes.

Comment: The reason I think this is the best answer is because of all the times people post a question here asking why their calculations give different probabilities than they ought to, and it turns out they just counted favorable outcomes out of an unequally-likely set of outcomes.